# Filtering/querying list of shortcuts in tmux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

One can list all keybindings using `PREFIX+?`. But there are a lot of shortcuts, so I want to filter the list of keybindings in tmux. For example, I want to see all the keybindings that has the word "pane" in itself.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try:

- in the console, type `$ tmux list-keys` to get the listing of all keybindings (the same list as with `prefix + ?`)
- now you can filter the list with `grep`. Here's the example: `$ tmux list-keys | grep 'pane'`